# Include dynamically generated content

Tags: python, flask

At the bottom of my base.html I'm trying to `include` an other .html file which is dynamically generated. So in order to do that, I'm calling a `.js` file which makes a GET request to that end point. Take a look;

```
# _base.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> ...
<script type=text/javascript src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/recent_posts.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>...
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
...
{% include 'recent_posts.html' %}
</body>
</html>

# recent_posts.js    
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/recent_posts',
        type: 'GET'
    });
});

# view for recent_posts
...
@recentPosts_blueprint.route('/recent_posts', methods=['GET'])
def recent_posts():
    vacation = Vacation.query.all()
    return render_template('recent_posts.html', vacation=vacation)


# recent_post.html
...
<h3>Recent Posts</h3>
{{ vacation }}
...
```

When the page loads I only get the `</h3>` tag and the text but not the data

Why? and How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, without duplicating the code, after some documentation reading, I found a solution. I've put the code in a function under `funcs.py` and added to the globals.

```
def recent_posts():
    data = []
    data_list = []
    vacation = Vacation.query.all()
    return vacation

app.jinja_env.globals.update(recent_posts=recent_posts)
```

And in the `__init__.py` I've added the func.py: `from project.funcs import funcs` So now I can do `{% set data  =  recent_posts() %}` in the `_base.html` or anywhere else and it will run the function and get my results back to the base.